# Rails nested resources creation - passing the user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of nested resources consisting of *users*, *books*, and *chapters*. Here's how it looks.

**Models**

```
class User
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, allow_destroy: true
end

class Book
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters, allow_destroy: true
end

class Chapter
  belongs_to :book
end
```

**Chapter Controller**

```
def create
    @chapter = @book.chapters.build(params[:chapter])
    if @chapter.save
        flash[:success] = "A new chapter created!"
        redirect_to blah blah
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

protected

    def get_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:chapter][:book_id]) || 
                         Book.find(params[:book_id])
    end
```

You might be wondering why I have that protected method. I'm trying to let users create chapters and books in separate pages and still have the convenience of having nested resources. So a user can create a chapter on the chapter creation page and associate the chapter with the right book via association form.

Currently I'm stuck because the chapter resource is not getting the user id it needs. I'm very new to web development so I might be doing some crazy things here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really want to get this to work.

EDIT: To give more detail on what I meant by "the chapter resource is not getting the user id it needs" - in the chapter model I wrote *validates :user_id, presence: true*. When I press the submit button on the chapter creation page, it gives an error saying user_id cannot be blank.

Comment: you to explain "Currently I'm stuck because the chapter resource is not getting the user id it needs" a bit more. are you getting errors? if not, are you not getting needed column saved in the database?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. So in the chapter model I wrote "validates :user_id, presence: true" and when I press submit on the form button it gives an error saying user_id cannot be blank. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: why do you need a user_id in your chapter model? i thought it's a nested resource where chapter belongs_to book belongs to user? so user_id should be in the book right?

Comment: I want to make sure that other users can't mess with my chapters. So it's there for validation purposes.

Comment: where do you intend to get user_id? input from a user? the current user? if it's there for validation purpose and you're checking for only presence, then is this field in the form for chapters?

Comment: The current user. I thought when you nest resources all the resources under User gets associated with user and user ids are automatically distributed so I have not put the field in the form for chapters. The main purpose of having the user_id pass down is to make sure a user can only mess with his own content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be sure that the current user owns the chapter, and therefore the book, change the `get_book` method to

```
def get_book
  @book = current_user.books.find(params.fetch(:chapter, {})[:book_id] || params[:book_id])
end
```

`params.fetch` makes sure that you don't get an exception when `params[:chapter]` is `nil`

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I take it passing the user_id is not the best thing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `Chapter` model should check that the `user_id` is present. Instead, the controller should have a before_filter that checks if the action is authorized for the current user.

Something like this:

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorized?, only: [:create]

  def create
    ...
  end

  private
    def authorized?
      current_user && current_user.owns? Chapter.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

`owns?` would then be implemented on the User model, and `current_user` would be implemented in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was under the impression that user ids can be automatically assigned to each nested model. I'll try this method and come back.